# Access memory address in c#

Tags: c#, memory-management, activex

I am interfacing with an ActiveX component that gives me a memory address and the number of bytes.

How can I write a C# program that will access the bytes starting at a given memory address?  Is there a way to do it natively, or am I going to have to interface to C++?  Does the ActiveX component and my program share the same memory/address space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly suggest you use an IntPtr and Marshal.Copy. Here is some code to get you started. 
memAddr is the memory address you are given, and bufSize is the size.

```
IntPtr bufPtr = new IntPtr(memAddr);
byte[] data = new byte[bufSize];
Marshal.Copy(bufPtr, data, 0, bufSize);
```

This doesn't require you to use unsafe code which requires the the /unsafe compiler option and is not verifiable by the CLR.

If you need an array of something other than bytes, just change the second line. Marshal.Copy has a bunch of overloads.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx) to copy the data from native memory into an managed array. This way you can then use the data in managed code without using [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) code.

Comment: This is probably a much more elegant way than using unsafe code.  My program now works with unsafe code; but, I will revisit it later to see if I can replace it with Marshal.Copy

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328688(VS.71).aspx) type.  This type (when used within an `unsafe` block) will allow you to use the memory handle from the ActiveX component.

Answer (score 1):

C# can use pointers.  Just use the 'unsafe' keyword in front of your class, block, method, or member variable (not local variables).  If a class is marked unsafe all member variables are unsafe as well.

```
unsafe class Foo
{

}

unsafe int FooMethod
{

}
```

Then you can use pointers with * and & just like C.

I don't know about ActiveX Components in the same address space.

Comment: I ended up using this solution after I posted the question.
_axetRecord1.SourceBufferMemoryPointer stores the location of the beginning of the memory buffer.

The following code does work:
[code]
short* memPtr;
memPtr = (short*)_axetRecord1.SourceBufferMemoryPointer;
[/code]

Comment: You have to pin the instance if you're going to pass it to native code though!