# .NET - copy data from specific segment:offset

Tags: c#, .net, memory, interop

Referring to this topic: [Access memory address in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972272/access-memory-address-in-c), I'm trying to understand how to address a memory location and extract data by knowing its hexadecimal segment:offset. Also, I believe the size can be variable. I would appreciate any advice on proceeding with this.

Comment: Are you talking about reading memory that belongs to another  application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want trouble...

```
        int bufSize = 12;

        IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr) (0xffff *16U + 5);                  

        byte[] data = new byte[bufSize];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, bufSize);
```

Comment: Henk, thanks, but it doesn't work. The array contains zeroes. Actually there's a 16-bit DEBUG.EXE tool which does the job fine (dumps contents of this memory address), but I'm running 64-bit machine and 16-bit apps support is not available. That's why I thought of doing it manually. I've tried running your code on 32-bit machine where DEBUG yields correct result, but still no success (same zeroes).

Comment: Also, the length is 8 bytes. But still the result is blank.

Comment: @Sphynx: I'm not at all surprised that a 16-bit debugger and a 64-bit app give different results. And to be clear, under windows each app gets its own address 0xffff:5, and they  can not see each others memory.

Comment: @Sphynx: A 16bit tool is probably quite old - as in from the days that processes could read each others memory if they wanted to. That is not possible today. This is controlled by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Managed applications run on platforms with a linear address space. There is no segment, there is no offset. There is only address and you can read and write at any address through [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx).

Comment: Any suggestions on converting such address to linear?

Comment: Found this: Segment:Offset = Segment x 16 + Offset. Now I need to figure out how to detect the number of bytes to be copied.

Comment: segment:offset addresses don't exist anymore

Comment: That is incorrect. Segment:offset is from old 16 bit architectures and no such addresses exist today in .Net. You cannot interface with an application that returns such addresses.

Comment: It's a static value I have (FFFF:5). Any way to convert it to the new architecture addressing scheme?

Comment: No, there is no way FFFF:5 is valid address on *any* platform, including 16 bit ones.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you just said. The address I mentioned above is segment:offset, but you suggested such addresses exist only in 16-bit applications? If it's a valid address, how to pass it to Marshal.Copy?

Comment: Perhaps you should read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx